# Use a list to create VirtualHost automatically

Tags: linux, bash

I really need your help :)
I Have a list of domain and directory and i need to create all the list automatically but i'm block.

My script:

```
list=$(cat litdom.txt)
for i in $list ; do

jfhdomaine=

ddomaine=

touch /home/test/$jfhdomaine.conf

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin mail@linux.com
        ServerName $jfdomain
        DocumentRoot $ddomaine
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin mail@linux.com
        ServerName $jfhdomain
        DocumentRoot $ddomain
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>" > /home/test/$jfdomaine.conf


a2ensite $jfhdomaine.conf

done
```

and my list is like this:

```
klml.freeware.com/
/var/www/html/viaja

linux.freeware.com/
/var/www/html/nicho/

vida.freeware.com/
/var/www/html/free/
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cat NEW.txt | xargs -L 2 | while read line; do

jfhdomaine=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`
ddomaine=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

THANKS :)

Comment: You have an incomplete `while` loop there, and you could use `xargs -L 2 <NEW.txt` instead of the pipe with `cat`.  It's also unclear why you don't just read two values with `read jfhdomain ddomaine` instead of running `awk` twice (or use two calls to `read` if the values are on separate lines).

Comment: it's not clear, i know this but i'm not a expert, and its works.